# Is it possible to upgrade graphics card in a laptop with a dedicated card?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card

Is it possible to upgrade graphics card in a laptop with a dedicated card? Specifically, I have a Acer Aspire E5-521G-60BX with a AMD Radeon R5 M240. If so, what are my options? Could I possibly go all the way up to an R9 series or do I have to stick with the R5 series?

Answer (score 3):

You can't, unfortunately, in most cases.

The gpu is most likely soldered on the mainboard and thus making it impossible for a normal man to change it.

Comment: nevermind found the answer